# How to use Apache AGE to connect one node to all nodes within a group of nodes?

Tags: postgresql, graph-databases, apache-age

So I have a csv with this header:

`start_id,strength,start_verse,end_verse`

Two line examples are these:

```
01001001,15,38012001,00000000
01001001,16,20008022,20008030
```

The first line means that the node with id `01001001` connects with strength 15 with the node id `38012001`.

The second line means that the node id `01001001` connects with strength 16 to **all the nodes between** `20008022` and `20008030`, sequentially, and here is where lies my problem:

How can I use Apache AGE to connect one vertex to all vertexes in a group?
I was using the load csv feature, but if anyone know any other means to do so, I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apache AGE currently does not have a function that creates edges in that way. However, you can use a Cypher query to establish relationships between vertices if they have a property like 'id' or any other distinguishing property.

In this way, you can create the vertices using the 'load_labels_from_file()' function (more about it [here](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/agload.html)), and then use a Cypher query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (v {id: 01001001})
    CREATE (v)-[:connects {strength: 16}]->(n)
    WHERE n.id >= 20008022 AND n.id <= 20008030
$$) AS (v agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is currently no shortcut to achieve exactly what you are looking for, it may be easier to simply edit the CSV file to create new rows for each connections with strength 16, for example:

```
start_id,strength,verse
01001001,15,38012001
01001001,16,20008022
01001001,16,20008023
01001001,16,20008024
01001001,16,20008025
01001001,16,20008026
01001001,16,20008027
01001001,16,20008028
01001001,16,20008029
01001001,16,20008030
```

Which then you can just import into AGE. It is relatively easy to do this change rather than manually making the connection inside AGE in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to write a Python script that will take data from your CSV file and then put that in the Apache age form.

```
01001001,15,38012001,00000000
For the first line you have to put the condition when the last column data is 0000 then only we have to connect to one specific node only.

01001001,16,20008022,20008030
For this one the condition would be such that (01001001) node will make edge of the attribute(strength: 16) to nodes ranging from (20008022-20008030)
```

01001001,15,38012001,00000000

The query for this line would be then:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (v {id: 01001001})
    CREATE (v)-[:connects {strength: 16}]->(n)
    WHERE n.id = 38012001
$$) AS (v agtype);
```

01001001,16,20008022,20008030

The query for that above line would be:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (v {id: 01001001})
    CREATE (v)-[:connects {strength: 16}]->(n)
    WHERE n.id >= 20008022 AND n.id <= 20008030
$$) AS (v agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before creating edges, it is important to create all the nodes first. This is necessary because if one node is supposed to be connected with a group of other nodes, it requires that all the nodes in that group already exist.

Assuming you have already created all the nodes, you can now use the following cypher query to create the edges:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
    MATCH (n {id: '01001001'})
    MATCH (m)
    WHERE m.id >= '20008022' AND m.id <= '20008030'
    CREATE (n)-[:CONNECTED_TO {strength: 15}]->(m)
$$) AS (result agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache AGE currently does not have a function that creates edges in that way but you can edit the CSV file to create new rows for each connection with strength 16 and then import it into AGE.
Here is the code that how to connect one vertex to all vertices in a group:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ('graph_name', $$  
MATCH (v {id: 01001001})  
UNWIND range(20008022, 20008030) AS n
CREATE (v)- [:connects {strength: 16}]-> (n)  
$$) AS (v agtype);
```

This query uses the `cypher()` function to execute a Cypher query that creates a connection between vertex `01001001` and all vertices with IDs between `20008022` and `20008030`. The `UNWIND` function is used to iterate over the range of IDs and create a new edge between the two vertices with a strength of 16